# XmlSerializer and emoji

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

The XmlSerializer has a hard time (= does not) deserialize content that includes emoji characters, for example `&#55357;&#56877;`. I've read that such characters are actually illegal in XML standard; however, they're needed if I want to faithfully represent chat conversations that include emoji. How can I deserialize and obtain a string that contains just those characters?

(I will have to deal with those characters later, but let's start with (de)serializing them :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. First test class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Test {
    [XmlElement("data")]
    public string Root { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var test = "<root><data>&#55357;&#56877;</data></root>";
var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
using (var reader = new StringReader(test)) {
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, new XmlReaderSettings() {
       CheckCharacters = false // key part
    })) {
        var obj = s.Deserialize(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

Using `CheckCharacters = false` with xml reader will prevent it from checking if any characters are outside the range of legal XML characters.